# How to set expiration date for external files?

Tags: page-speed

I have a site included lots of external files, most of them are gif format. I have no control on the external files, but have to use them(with permission). When I check the site using Google Pagespeed, I got very low score(31) even though the page load is fast.

One of the high priority suggestion is to leverage browser caching by setting an expiration date. However, all the files are on external links. I have already set the expiration date for local files.

Comment: For the future, questions like this are usually better suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com -- Those guys are well versed in how to optimize sites when dealing with external resources (and how to optimize the stuff you're serving), where we're more geared toward "How can I tweak Apache/nginx/IIS to serve pages faster?" type questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are outside of your control, so you have three options:

1. Copy them to your server
2. Get the remote server admin to change it
3. Ignore it.